# Floats, Decimals, or Integers

Tags: ruby, activerecord, decimal

I have a rails app that process some data, and some of these data include numbers with decimals such as `1.9943`, and division between these numbers and other integers. I wanted to know what the best way to store this was.

I thought of storing the numbers that would retain integers as integers and numbers that could become decimals as decimals. Although it was in a weird format like

```
#<BigDecimal:7fda470aa9f0,'0.197757E1',18(18)>
```

it seems to perform the correct arithmetic when I divide two decimal numbers or a decimal with an integer. When I try to divide integers with integers, it doesn't work correctly. I thought rails would automatically convert the result into a proper decimal, but it seems to keep it as integer and strip the remainders. Is there anything I can do about this?

And what would be the best way to store this type of information? Should I store it all as decimals, or maybe floats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to divide two integers without losing precision, you need to cast one of them to a `Float` or `BigDecimal` first:

```
irb(main):007:0> 2/3
=> 0
irb(main):008:0> Float(2)/3
=> 0.666666666666667
```

I am a bit confused when you say that you get different results when you divide a Float/Integer vs. Integer/Float?  These should have the same result:

```
irb(main):010:0> Integer(2)/Float(3)
=> 0.666666666666667
irb(main):011:0> Float(2)/Integer(3)
=> 0.666666666666667
irb(main):012:0> String( BigDecimal('2')/3 )
=> "0.666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667E0"
irb(main):013:0> String( 2/BigDecimal('3') )
=> "0.666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667E0"
```

Can you provide a code example?

As far as storage goes, any integer data should be stored as an `Integer` regardless of its expected use in future calculations.

Storing Floats vs. BigDecimals depends on how much precision you require.  If you don't require much precision, a `Float` will provide a double-precision representation.  If you require a high degree of precision, `BigDecimal` will provide an arbitrary-precision representation.

**Related:** [Ruby Numbers](http://www.public.traineronrails.com/courses/ruby/pages/007-rubynumbers.html) - Explains the difference between Integers, Floats, BigDecimals, and Rationals

Comment: This works except I used BigDecimal instead of float. Could you tell me why I should use float instead?

Comment: @user2158382 BigDecimal is used when you need an arbitrarily precise representation.  Float is used when a double-precision representation is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need big precision to have problems with floats
You should better avoid as much as possible floats.
Ex: 123.6 - 123 => in floats it will give you 0,59..
in BigDecimal you will have 0.6